# To show the given limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Given the following function
$$f(x)=2 x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) ~~ \text{for} ~~ x \neq 0 ,$$
to show that $\displaystyle \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ not exist, I take a sequence $x_n = \dfrac{1}{2n \pi}$ and conclude that though $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
$$f \left( x_n \right) = -\cos (2n\pi) = -1 \not\rightarrow f(0).$$

Is this argument correct ? Or do I have to come up with two sequences, both of which converge to zero but the function has two different limits ?

Comment: It is certainly true that **one way** to show f(x) does not have a limit as x → 0 is to find two sequences {a_n} and {b_n} such that the limits as n  → ∞ of f(a_n) and of f(b_n) both exist, but are unequal.

Answer (score 5):

Your suggested argument does not show that that the limit does not exist. The argument where
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)
$$
needs to hold is for continuity at $a$, not the limit existing. For instance, consider the function
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
0, & x \ne 0 \\
1, & x = 0 \end{cases}
$$
Then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists, and equals to zero. It just happens to not agree with $f(0)$, so it's not continuous.

In fact, your function is not even defined at $x=0$, so it is nonsensical to speak of $f(0)$ in the first place.

---

If you want to show that the limit does not exist, it would indeed be sufficient to find two sequences, $(x_n),(y_n)$, such that $x_n \to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ but $f(x_n) \to X$ and $f(y_n) \to Y$ for $X \ne Y$.